# cpanel node.js Can't acquire lock for app: app

Tags: node.js, express, deployment, cpanel

i am trying to deploy a node.js app. after creating and installing modules using cpanel interface. when i run script, i get this error: Can't acquire lock for app: app.
any idea?

Comment: I've had this problem before and I had to contact the provider to get the app reset. If you have shell access you can apparently kill the running node processes and that will bring things back to normal.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Remove `.lock` file at source `/home/<repo>/nodevenv/node/`. Additionally, before executing `npm install`, you need to stop the application.

Answer (score 6):

- Remove lock from home/nodevenv/{domain}/.lock
- Stop the app
- Change node version to be up to date with your application
- npm install all dependencies
- Restart the app

Answer (score 3):

Delete .lock file from /home/nodevenv/

Answer (score 1):

try a look at this:

https://cloudlinux.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360010988820--NodeJS-Selector-not-Working-with-an-Error-Can-t-acquire-lock-for-app

You need to access via terminal to kill the process.

I'm still trying to run a node.js application that not expose a web interface but works like a bot.

Answer (score 1):

My solution
Open File Manager find .lock:

```
/home/[username]/nodevenv/[domain]
```

then remove .lock file

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by going the `virtualenv` folder and deleting the `.lock` file

Answer (score 0):

Copy this: `nodevenv/public_html/`

Visit your Cpanel > file manager > Then Paste it and Search for it

You will find all of your nodejs projects.

From there just open the nodejs app on which you are getting the error.

Simply, Delete the .lock file from there.